# How to import SketchUp models into After Effects CS6

Tags: 3d, 3d-modelling, sketchup, after-effects

I'm having a hard time finding a way to get SketchUp models from Google's [3D warehouse](http://sketchup.google.com/3dwarehouse/) into After Effects CS6.

As [this tutorial](http://www.damonledet.com/2009/03/using-google-sketchup-models-in-after-effects-cs4/) describes, in AE CS5.5 and before, it was possible to find a .kmz file in Google's 3D warehouse, open that in Photoshop, save it as a .psd file, and then open that .psd file in After Effects.

However, Adobe now [states that](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/aftereffects/cs/using/WS3878526689cb91655866c1103906c6dea-7f29a.html) "In After Effects CS6, support for 3D object layers in PDS [*sic?*] files is no longer supported."

After Effects CS6 can apparently import SoftimagePIC, RLA, RPF, OpenEXR, and Electric Image EI 3D models.

How can I get a .skp or .kmz SketchUp file into one of these formats? I've tried SketchUp 7 and 8, but both can only save as .skp. Blender supports a larger number of filetypes but I haven't found one that After Effects will recognize yet.

Alternatively, is there a resource for simple free 3D models in a format that After Effects CS6 can import?

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After effects can't import any model.
all you can do is to render stuff in your 3D app onto picture or video as you normally do, then do the same but render depth information as rpf. Then combine that in AE. you won't be able to change camera position but you'll be able to apply 3d effects such as light.
But to export stuff in a way AE will recognise you need expensive app such as 3dmax or cinema4d. Free stuff like sketchup, or even pro version of it is just a joke, not a real `3D app`.

Answer (score -1):

it's possible.
in case you're still searching - or in case somebody lands here:
first export object data from sketchup to blender:
http://ssimpossible.blogspot.nl/2010/10/technically-second-video-tutorial.html
then from blender to AE:
http://cg.bartekskorupa.com/b2ae/

Comment: The second link is about importing motion data, not 3D models.